# Ubuntu 20.04 integrated webcam failure

Tags: webcam

I am having trouble with my integrated web cam . It works at times then stops and I get a no device error Acer Aspire 5733z 10 years old. This is with cheese.
Here are the terminal errors and log when I run cheese
Grateful for any help as it can work at times frustrating
`assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed`

```
(cheese:10721): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:03:22.976: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:10721): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:03:22.976: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:10721): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:03:22.976: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:10721): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:03:22.976: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:10721): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:03:22.976: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:10721): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:03:22.976: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:10721): CRITICAL **: 14:03:22.976: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

log

```
15:36:52 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 0, lost async page write
15:36:52 kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32768 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
15:36:52 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 access beyond end of device
15:36:52 kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 15591920, async page read
15:36:52 kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 124735360 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
15:36:52 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 access beyond end of device
15:36:52 kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 124735360 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
15:36:52 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 access beyond end of device
15:31:14 kernel: uvcvideo: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
15:20:43 kernel: usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
15:17:45 pulseaudio: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
15:17:20 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
15:16:11 kernel: usb 1-1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device


lsblk -f --exclude 7
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                   
├─sda1
│    vfat         F867-96FD                               511M     0% /boot/efi
├─sda2
│                                                                     
└─sda5
     ext4         e0708372-2724-435d-9b18-11664ecad8de  859,5G     1% /
sr0                                                                   
david@david-Aspire-5733Z:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=ums-realtek, 480M
```

Comment: Please add outputs of `lsblk -f --exclude 7` and `lsusb -t` to the question.

Comment: NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                   
├─sda1
│    vfat         F867-96FD                               511M     0% /boot/efi
├─sda2
│                                                                     
└─sda5
     ext4         e0708372-2724-435d-9b18-11664ecad8de  859,5G     1% /
sr0

Comment: /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=ums-realtek, 480M

Comment: That what i get with these 2 command thanks for your interst !

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the outputs to the end of your original question. Comments are ***not*** for adding extra information to your question!

Comment: sorry thanks for the tip